# Is subsonic in asp.net is a good approach or not?

Tags: asp.net, subsonic

I am trying to make an enterprise application in asp.net. Is Subsonic a better approach or not?

How do I write code using Subsonic in asp.net?

Or is there another way to access data from the database if we want to fetch thousands of record.

Comment: .NET ORM comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Comment: This question is too vague, there is no objective answer without fully understanding your requirements. A detailed question may be suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com as the answer involves very little code and is subjective.

Comment: the subsonic 3 is extreme slow. The subsonic 2 is fast, but need more optimization, but is very good. I use subsonic 2 on an enterprise application with my optimization, more than 300 tables, 4 database and I have super fast response and good stability, easy development.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options here, I personally prefer **Entity Framework**, but I know that **NHibernate** is also a *powerful and widely used* ORM.

Personally I don't suggest going with **Linq2Sql**. **Entity Framework** is better and like a *successor* to **Linq2Sql**.

**NHibernate** is very powerful , but looks more tricky to me (compared to **Entity Framework**).

I have no idea about **SubSonic**, but I've heard of it.

***Choosing between them?* It's completely up to you.**

Links below may help you choose wisely:

[Subsonic Vs NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384/subsonic-vs-nhibernate)

[Subsonic 3 VS Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153672/subsonic-3-vs-entity-framework)

[Entity Framework 4 vs NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639043/entity-framework-4-vs-nhibernate)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using LINQ to SQL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

LINQ to SQL provides an easy way to interface with your database for your enterprise application.

There is also plenty of documentation on how to use LINQ to SQL online compared to other methods.

- [Part 1: Introduction to LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)
- [Part 2: Defining our Data Model Classes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx)
- [Part 3: Querying our Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx)
- [Part 4: Updating our Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx)
- [Part 5: Binding UI using the <asp:LinqDataSource> Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx)
- [Part 6: Retrieving Data Using Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)
- [Part 7: Updating our Database using Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx)
- [Part 8: Executing Custom SQL Expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx)
- [Part 9: Using a Custom LINQ Expression with the <asp:LinqDataSource> Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options.

You should research a few at least before making your choice.

I would consider...

- Entity framework
- nHibernate
- Linq 2 SQL
- Dapper